# What does Coal Touch do?

Tags: pocket-mine

I unlocked a new uncommon card called Coal Touch.   I figured it would turn everything I mine in to coal, but I didn't end up seeing that.  What does the card Coal Touch do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the article *Pocket Mine: Part 2 of the Top 10 Tips and Cheats to Dig Deeper and Get Rich*, coal touch will only turn regular dirt blocks into coal, not all blocks.

(http://www.writerparty.com/party/pocket-mine-part-2-top-10-tips-cheats-dig-deeper-get-rich/)

Answer (score 1):

Coal Touch does what it says on the tin. Basically, any block that is NOT a block that you would usually get some sort of stone from (coal, diamond, gold, etc), will give you coal for whatever amount of time (in your case, 5 seconds, but you can fuse multiples of this card together to make it last longer).

Also, crates will not give you coal during this time (either the prize crates or the bomb/grenade/gas crates) - they will still act normally.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the "touch" overrides other block types... so if you have coal touch active you get a coal from all the ore blocks too... instead of a gold, iron or diamond.